# Cannot install node modules after doing npm cache clean --force

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can anyone help me with this? I did the following steps to try fix directory error but ended up breaking something.

[image]

After doing the following steps, I cannot install node modules anymore.

This is the error when starting the app:

**Error: Cannot find module 'express'**

Then when I tried `npm install express` or `npm install`, these are the errors:

[image]

[image]

I hope someone can help me with my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try installing Python?

Comment: @ChrisG nope, i believe that has nothing to do with the error since i am not using python

Comment: Yes, but `node-gyp` requires it, and it looks like you're using `node-gyp` to install some things.

Comment: Hi @Andy, i'm wondering also but i'm not using `node-gyp` that's why its hard to track which is the real problem

Comment: When some modules install they automatically use node-gyp to compile some things. You may be better off reinstalling node so that it can install all the required dependencies.

Comment: @Andy thanks but reinstalling node still results the same

Comment: i found the error, i overwrite my local npm to the latest version, after i downgrade its working fine again. thanks!